# Permission denied (publickey) when try ssh into Oracle Cloud

Tags: ssh, oracle

I downloaded two keys ssh-key-2023-02-09.key and ssh-key-2023-02-09.key.pub. I did chmod 400 ssh-key-2023-02-09.key

ssh -i ssh-key-2023-02-09.key user@ip

Permission denied (publickey)

Answer (score 0):

Try below points to dig more.

1. Are you using same private key for sshing instance which you are referring with `ssh -i` command?
2. Add `-vv` option during ssh command to get more verbose output.
3. You are using ssh key for correct user/ip normally it `opc` user.

Comment: On instances created from an Ubuntu platform image the default user is named "ubuntu".